# Problem with derived class in c++ with no data member

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning c++ inheritance and facing problems with the following exercise to create a base class A and a derived class B with certain requirements. I have my answer written down below, but there seems to be some problems with it. I also have a few question at the end of this post.

[image: Class A]

```
class A {
    private:
        int x;
    protected:
        A (): x(0) { } 
        A (int n): x(n) { }
        int get() const {return x;}
    public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

[image: Class B]

```
class B : public A {
    public:
        B (): { A(); }
        B (int n): { A(n); }
        virtual void foo() { std::cout << get();}
};
```

My questions are:

1. I'm pretty sure my code is not correctly written, but can anyone tell me what's incorrect?
2. Since `x` is private in `A`, `B` wouldn't be able to inherit that data member. So how is `B` able to invoke the constructor?
3. I'm pretty sure that `A` is an abstract class, but is `B` an abstract class too?

Comment: Regarding point 1, did try running it? Did it work?

Comment: The constructor of `B` should call the constructor of `A`. When you write `B (): { A(); }`, you are creating an instance of `A` in the constructor of `B`. `B` cannot access to `x` because it's private. But, `B`can call all protected and public members of `A` including its constructor. `A` is not abstract. You just can't create a new instance by yourself.

Comment: Good practice : in B you are overriding `foo`, so use the `override` keyword, not longer `virtual`

Comment: Romha - class A is abstract, because of this line - function foo() = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's *almost* okay, there's two thing that is wrong:

   - First you have an empty constructor initializer list in the `B` constructors. That will lead to build errors.
   - Then in the `B` constructor the statement `A()` creates a temporary `A` object, which is promptly discarded and destructed. You need to "call" the parent class constructor from the `B` constructor initializer list:

     ```
     B() : A() { /* Empty */ }
     ```

     You meed to do the same for the parameterized `B` constructor as well.
2. You can't access `private` members in the base-class, but `protected` is okay. That's now `protected` works with `public` inheritance: The child class can access the base class protected members.
3. Since you override `foo` with an implementation `B` is not abstract, there's no abstract members of `B`.

Comment: Thanks but one more question: B() : A() { } ; B (int n): A(n) { } I understand the correct way of writing now, but what does the constructor actually do? if I do " B object(5) " in my main function, what does that give me? a type B object that can access it's base class member? but itself doesn't have a member.

Comment: @Jeremy With `B object(5);` you create an instance of `B` named `object`. Using `object` you can access all *public* members of `B` and its base-classes.

Comment: private *hides*, but does not *remove* parts. There is a whole `A` in each `B`